# What's it called when a compiler faces a reference to a thing defined later in the code?

Tags: compiler-construction, terminology

There's a common issue you have to deal with when designing a compiler: one line of code might refer to something defined on a later line.  For example:

```
 function f() { return g(5); }
 function g() { do something; }
```

The first line refers to the function `g` that hasn't been defined yet, so the compiler has to keep track of this reference to `g` in the current scope.  When `g` gets defined on the next line, the compiler can determine what the previous line referred to.

What is this called?

I know there's a term for it in compiler design, but I just can't remember it.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696562/forward-reference-vs-forward-declaration][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696562/forward-reference-vs-forward-declaration

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, thanks for the link, but I think there's something broken in your comment.

Comment: I've managed to mess up the formatting, true, but either of the links takes you to the page I had in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called a *Forward reference*.