# How compiler understand self referential structures ? should it be infinite recursion?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, queue, stack

```
  class LinkedlistNode {
   int data;
   LinkedlistNode next=null ;

  }`
```

from the first day I got to the concept of linkedlist , I was never convinced how can we define a node inside a node . How can we define something while we are already defining it ?

I tried to ask chat gpt he told me that compiler knew earlier that there is class called node but its definition isn't completed yet so it waits until classes are loaded by JVM but I wasn't convinced . Then on Quora I saw an answer says that pointers or references already have a fixed size.

Comment: Are you talking about the class definition, or about instances of the class (the actual linked lists)? *"define a node inside a node"* seems to talk about an actual linked list instance, but then you write *"how can we define something..."* which seems to refer to the class...

Comment: I am asking about the linkrdlist concept if it is about chained nodes how the node is written like that ?

Comment: *"how the node is written like that"*: like what? There is no node in the code you shared. Nodes would be created with `new LinkedListNode()`...

Comment: what I mean is how when we define the node class inside it we defined the reference next which is of same type?

Comment: OK, so you are not asking about the nodes then. You are asking about the class definition.

Comment: yes , I think so :)

Answer (score 3):

Compilers can do things differently (like in [one or multiple passes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673818/difference-between-one-pass-and-multi-pass-compilers)), but we can imagine this process:

When a compiler parses the code, it builds a table of symbols (names), which at the start is empty. For instance, we could imagine that table like this:

| name | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | .... | ... |

When parsing `class LinkedlistNode` the symbol `LinkedlistNode` is added to that table:

| name | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LinkedlistNode | class | (empty) |

Then `int data` is processed: the class gets its first member with a (primitive) type that is known:

| name | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LinkedlistNode | class | { int data } |

When `LinkedlistNode next` is encountered, the name `LinkedListNode` is recognised, so there is no mystery there: the class gets its second member:

| name | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LinkedlistNode | class | { int data, LinkedListNode next } |

We just have introduced a backreference, a loop if you want. It was not a problem that the *value* part of `LinkedListNode` was not yet finalised. The only thing that matters here is that `LinkedListNode` is an entry in our symbol table at the moment we encounter it again -- which is the case here.

Without any issue this graph is created:

[image]

Be aware that this is not an *instance* of `LinkedListNode`. It is "just" the class definition.

Once you start creating actual nodes with `new LinkedListNode()`, the `next` member will be initialised with `null`. Then you *could* replace that `null` with another `new LinkedListNode()`, ...etc, and build your linked list.

Comment: great ! so to get that right next is not an actual node because of that we don't have an infinite recursion right ?so whwn we make a node it would have a next ref which knows that it points to ADT which is the node after it

Comment: In a `class` definition you don't create nodes. You just define types. And when that class has been defined, all involved types are known and ready to be used when you create an instance.

Answer (score 1):

`next` is a reference to a node, not an instance of a node. It is essentially a pointer to a node.