# No error like class not defined

Tags: java, compilation

I have the following starting code for a binary tree. I just wanted to know, if the `BinaryTree` class is not yet defined at Line A and Line B. Why do I not get compilation error at Line A and Line B reporting - `BinaryTree not defined`.
I am assuming, Line C is where the class is completely defined.

```
public class BinaryTree {
private int data;
private BinaryTree left;  // Line A
private BinaryTree right;  // Line B

public BinaryTree(int num) {
this.data = num;
this.left = null;
this.right = null;
}
// getters and setters.
}  // Line C
```

Comment: It doesn't matter in Java, thats not C++ where we need header files.

Comment: Is this the full code for the class verbatim?

Comment: This code compiles just fine.  (By itself, as is, with just a `main()` method added for the program.)  Do you have an example which demonstrates the problem you're describing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on tkausl's comment, here is the Java language spec regarding scoping:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3

Specifically:

> The scope of a top level type (§7.6) is all type declarations in the package in which the top level type is declared.

If you jump to section 7.6, there's even an example that addresses your question: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6

> **Example 7.6-2. Scope of Top Level Types**
>
> ```
> package points;
> class Point {
>     int x, y;           // coordinates
>     PointColor color;   // color of this point
>     Point next;         // next point with this color
>     static int nPoints;
> }
> class PointColor {
>     Point first;        // first point with this color
>     PointColor(int color) { this.color = color; }
>     private int color;  // color components
> }
> ```
>
> This program defines two classes that use each other in the declarations of their class members. Because the class types Point and PointColor have all the type declarations in package points, including all those in the current compilation unit, as their scope, this program compiles correctly. That is, forward reference is not a problem.

And just for completeness, forward reference (I had to look this up too...):
[Forward reference vs. forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696562/forward-reference-vs-forward-declaration)

**TLDR**: The Java spec says this should be OK, so it is.