# Forward referencing in Java

Tags: java

I have a method:

```
void foo() {
  int y = 5 + x;
  int x = 2;
}
```

Will it compile or not??
I think it should. They say `Java` support forward referencing i.e. I can use a variable before it is declared. Am I right??

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I think I had to edit my answer 5 times to get it right.

Comment: You also might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696562/forward-reference-vs-forward-declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't compile, because inside method you are trying to use variable x, which not exists. Inside method code is executed line by line.

This code will work:

```
public class Test
{
    void example()
    {
        int y = 5 + x;
    }

    int x = 5;
}
```

This is caused by the fact, that forward referencing working only for fields inside class.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 4):

You don't need other people to tell if it compiles. Just run the compiler **yourself**.

Another edit: *forward declarations* only work with **methods**, but not with *fields*:

This does **not** compile:

```
public class Test {
  int y = 5 + x;
  int x=  2;
}
```

but this compiles:

```
public class Test {
  int y = 5 + x();
  int x() { return 2};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... Why won't you try it? That way, you will get the answer without asking.  [Java Compiler Online](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php)

To answer your question however, a variable has to be assigned before being used. Java itself is not forward referencing. How would the compiler know the value of an unassigned variable?

[Forward Refencing In Java](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-are-the-forward-reference-rules/9)
Basically, as the page shows, it is possible to create an ugly hack if you really need forward referencing. I wouldn't do that though, but rather always store the value of a variable in for instance a class, then use `getter` methods to get the value of the variable. This would be much more appropriate than using the ugly hacks that they suggest on that page.

So, Java could be forward referencing, but the language itself is not.